# WiX - Copying Properties Between Dialogs

Tags: .net, wix

It's Friday and I'm probably fried from a long week. Is there an obvious way to copy properties from one dialog to another?

I don't see a way to specify a <SetProperty> or <CustomAction> to be sequenced after a specific dialog.

Is this obviously a WiX anti-pattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first dialog of a wizard loop exists in the UI sequence.  The rest of the dialogs are brought in via MSI ControlEvents (WiX Publish Element).  ControlEvents can be ordered so if you have  custom action that needs to be fired when the user clicks next you have to wire it up as a control event.

[Publish Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_publish.htm)

Comment: Thanks for explaining how the "wizard loop" fits into the UI sequence - that clarifies things immensely. And this also confirms the approach mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3582370/55574) which is also greatly appreciated. I hadn't come across this idiom until now.